# Register instance into builder from NServiceBus behaviour

Tags: unity-container, nservicebus

I have a web api which sends commands to endpoints. I've created message a mutator which adds a custom header with a serialized IAuthenticationInformation instance.

What I need to do in the receiving endpoints is intercept this header (presumably in a Behavior), deserialize it into an IAuthenticationInformation and register it into the child container which will build the handlers to return it when requested.

I've got everything to the point of registering the instance into the container. The problem is that the context.Builder doesn't provide any Register operation.
How can I achieve this?

Notes:

1. I'm using v6 (I found a way of doing this in v5 using the PipelineExecutor, but this doesn't seem to work any more).
2. I'm using Unity, but I'd prefer a container independent solution
3. This issue seems very common to me, as I need this for a couple of other scenarios (i.e registering a unit of work with a given db connection), so I don't understand why is so difficult to find a solution. Should I be looking at another approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is a variation of the [Appending username using headers](http://docs.particular.net/samples/username-header/) sample.

Add the UnityContainer as a constructor dependency in the IncomingMessageBehavior.

This will give you a child container to register your instance with.

Comment: This seems to be a good answer to my question (although not container independent) so I mark it as the answer, but I won't be following this approach because I got a different suggestion: register the dependencies with a lifetime of unit of work and in the behaviour call Initialize on them passing the data from the header. It is a better approach in this case, because we don't create a dependency to when nsb instantiates the dependencies and also to the container. You can read the full conversation here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/particularsoftware/AprrsD3G7gM/Tkoh-SVOEQAJ